# Flex mojos runtime localization support

Tags: localization, flexmojos, flex-mojos

I've got a flex application built by flex-mojos maven plugin (flex-mojos version 4.2 - I know it is old and not supported anymore, but it works ok for us).
Now we need to get the application localized. And we'd like to use the **runtime** localization (when all resources contained in separate swf files, one for each locale, and loaded at runtime). According to Adobe, in order to get these .swf files, one needs to run mxmlc command from commandline.
As far as I understand from the flex-mojos docs, the plugin won't generate these resource swfs on it's own, it will only copy the ones generated manually. The new flex-mojos version 7.0 and 7.1 doesn't have the possibility to automatically make runtime locales either.  Does anybody know if there is any way to automate this via flex-mojos? Will it ever be supported?

Comment: I don't quite understand your statement that FM doesn't support runtime locales. Both 4.2 up to 7.0.1 all support compiled and runtime locales. It's just the syntax changed from 4.x to 5.x (I think). Could you explain in a little more detail, what you are trying to do and what's exactly going wrong?

Comment: Hi Cristofer! Runtime locales in flex are swf files. What flex-mojos does when we say it "supports runtime localization" - it includes already generated swfs into the build. But these swfs containing actual resorces, MUST be generated from .properties files, via running mxmlc compiler from the command line manually. What I expected flex-mojos to do is to generate resources swfs from .properties files, not requiring a developer to do this step before launching maven build.

Comment: No, in my projects I have directories "src/main/locales/en_US/mycoolcomp.properties" and if using compiled locales these are included in the output and when using runtime locales the corresponding rb.swc files are generated.

Comment: Just have a look at the examples in the Flexmojos Testsuite at: https://github.com/chrisdutz/flexmojos/tree/flexmojos-7.x/flexmojos-testing/flexmojos-test-harness/projects/concept (Look at the tests starting with "I10N")